# How to prepare a consensus including overhangs using forward and reverse fastq files from sanguer sequencing?

Tags: alignment, pear, sequencing

I am having trouble merging my pre-trimmed fastq files to merge with the inclusion of the overhangs/nonoverlapping reads at either end. could any one provide a solution with bbmerge? I tried to use PEAR but it gave me only overlapped consensus excluding overhangs. I want overhangs appended to the overlapped region as final consensus.

for example,

@S1_A01_015_F ATTTATTTTTGGTGCTTTTTCTGGTGTAGTAGGAACTACATTATCTGTTTTAATTAGAATGGAATTAGCACAACCCGGTAATCAAATTTTTGCTGGGAATCATCATTTATATAATGTTGTTGTTACAGCACATGCATTTATTATGATTTTTTTTATGGTTATGCCTGTTTTAATAGGTGGTTTTGGTAATTGGTTTGTACCTTTAATGATTGGTGCTCCAGATATGGCTTTTCCTCGTATGAATAATATAAGTTTTTGGTTATTACCACCATCATTATTATTATTAGTTTCTTCAGCTATTGTTGAATCAGGTGCAGGTACTGGTTGGACTGTATATCCTCCTTTATCAAGTGTACAAGCACATTCAGGTCCTTCAGTAGATTTAGCTATTTTTAGTTTACATTTATCAGGTATTTCTTCTTTATTAGGTGCTATTAATTTTTTATCTACTATTTATAATATGAGAGCTCCAGGTTTAAGTTTTCATAGATTACCTTTATTTGTTTGGGCTATATTTATTACTGCTTTTTTATTATTATTAACTTTACCTGTATTAGCTGGTGCAATTACTATGTTATTAACTGATAGAAACTTAAATACATCTTTTTACGATCCATCAGGCGGAGGAGATCCTGTATTATACCAACATTTATTTTGGTTTTTCGGCAACCCCGGAAG +

9>%**ROOAB,78K[[[[W>W:0G6J@RP_J__Y_TPK_W_MRP\_W;W____\W______W__\W_________WK__RW________RKWWW__RW__W_WRW________________WWWW_\YW___WWWW______WW_WWW_____W_________________\S______LRRW_____Y_____________W___________________________________W________________________________WRRWWW______________________________________________________RRR_____________________O_____________________________________________________[[[[R[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[WW[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[R[[[[[[W[T[[[[[[[[[[[[R[[[[[[W[[R[[[MQ[[SO[W[LJB[[HMLWRT[[UPRSSSSJ=ISLM[ISIHKSS>@[IDD''&&&&<A5-((5

@S1_A01_015_R CTCCTCGCCTGATGGATCGTAAAAGATGTATTTAAGTTTCTATCAGTTAATAACATAGTAATTGCACCAGCTAATACAGGTAAAGTTAATAATAATAAAAAAGCAGTAATAAATATAGCCCAAACAAATAAAGGTAATCTATGAAAACTTAAACCTGGAGCTCTCATATTATAAATAGTAGATAAAAAATTAATAGCACCTAATAAAGAAGAAATACCTGATAAATGTAAACTAAAAATAGCTAAATCTACTGAAGGACCTGAATGTGCTTGTACACTTGATAAAGGAGGATATACAGTCCAACCAGTACCTGCACCTGATTCAACAATAGCTGAAGAAACTAATAATAATAATGATGGTGGTAATAACCAAAAACTTATATTATTCATACGAGGAAAAGCCATATCTGGAGCACCAATCATTAAAGGTACAAACCAATTACCAAAACCACCTATTAAAACAGGCATAACCATAAAAAAAATCATAATAAATGCATGTGCTGTAACAACAACATTATATAAATGATGATTCCCAGCAAAAATTTGATTACCGGGTTGTGCTAATTCCATTCTAATTAAAACAGATAATGTAGTTCCTACTACACCAGAAAAAGCACCAAAAATTAAATATAAAGTACCTATGTCTTTATGATTTGTTGAAAA +

B+'2+(0C2W:0[C4'L4('*)/=1:?HJ[J<=7____HH_GJI_FS_Y__PP_R___TN_\T_\M__\OY___**RR_______W**____\OSYYW_Y___\YCLW_____W_\WW__\Y_YWYWW___Y___W_\SAG<KQY_WRW_____YWQWY_O\EYYQN_WC_\Y___\Y___****Y_____YWW_Y____WQY_Y_Y***_*Y__KYYWLLW_SWWO_OY*\Y___________YYLLWQE*\R__\YMYYOOY___________YYYYY\OOY_***N_SRFG__Y\YYY_YORR_Y__Y__YR___YYYOY__________Y____LYY_OO_Y_____L_Y___YY_________O______________YYLJOYH?=OL___________MU_U***________[NUNMOUURWOQUUUPIIW[OMWOU7?OUUUPWU[[[UUN[WNLW[[WWUWNMU[[U[U[UDLC[QSHRWRSPWQMPQS[VTS[JJPPS[TTTT[[[PQR[[[[[RRJHMRTQQRR[W[R[[LQQSW@MLA9J1QQKL

I tried PEAR and bbmerge. PEAR gave me only aligned region as a consensus and with bbmerge I could not figure out to solve it.